# php cURL, wait before returning site

Tags: php, url, curl, response, wait

I'm using cURL to get some elements from another site. The problem is that the other site loads the elements I need after 1-2 seconds. So I dont get them through cURL.

Is there any way to make cURL wait a couple of seconds on the other site before returning it to me?

Comment: try to figure out where the content is being loaded from and load the content directly with curl.

Comment: You need to set a bigger timeout: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php CURLOPT_TIMEOUT. But it will return anyway when the other site returns its content.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sleep to delay the execution:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Answer (score 0):

If the content that you want to get appears with a delay, it is most probably retrieved with an AJAX call.

Use your browser's developer tools to check for AJAX (XHR) calls. For example, if you use Google Chrome, press F12 (or cmd+alt+I on a Mac) and open Network panel.

Click XHR to filter by AJAX requests. Open/refresh the page and click on the results to see which call contains the data that you need. Then use its URL in a curl request to fetch your data.

Answer (score 0):

IF the site is loading content after loading the page, then it probably means its using separate ajax requests (JavaScript) to fetch that content.

You will have to emulate those requests using curl or something else...
Use browser developer tools to find exactly what requests are being made. You will also probably have to parse the original page for some parameters and then make the curl call.